# How to show that series converges absolutely?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

The problem:

Show that $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(\frac{n\pi}{12})}{\ln(n)}$$ converges Conditionally or Absolutely.

Showing that it converges without the absolute value, I have done by using Dirichlet's Theorem. Showing that $\frac{1}{\ln(n)}$ is decreasing and that the partial sum of $\sin(\frac{n\pi}{12})$ is bounded. However how can one show that it converges or diverges in absolute value?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Saying that $\sin(n\pi/12)$ is bounded is not enough. You want the partial sums to be bounded.

Comment: I attempted to show that by using $$sinr\theta = \frac{cos(r-1/2)\theta - cos(r+1/2)\theta}{2sin(\theta/2)}$$

Comment: Yes it's correct.

Comment: It won't converge absolutely. Sine has absolute value $\ge1/2$ often enough, and $\ln n$ tends to zero too slowly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that infinite sum of (positive) reciprocals of the sequence $(\ln(an+b))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is divergent for all $a, b>0$ (by comparison test or integral test). Since $\sin(\pi+\theta)=-\sin(\theta)$ for any $\theta,$ lets check $\sin\left(\dfrac{n\pi}{12}\right)$ for $n=0, 1, 2, \cdots, 11.$

\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
  n & \sin\left(\dfrac{n\pi}{12}\right) \\ 
\hline
   0, 12 & 0 \\
\hline
   1, 11 & \dfrac{\sqrt6-\sqrt2}{4} \\
\hline
   2, 10 & \dfrac12 \\
\hline
   3, 9 & \dfrac{\sqrt2}2 \\ 
\hline
   4, 8 & \dfrac{\sqrt3}2 \\
\hline
   5, 7 & \dfrac{\sqrt6+\sqrt2}{4} \\
\hline
   6, 30 & 1 \\ 
\hline
\end{array}

Assuming the absolute convergence we can rearrange the series into $12$ divergent series, according to values in the above table, which is a contradiction.